# Tensorlfow, Running Error

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I want to know why this error occured.
The input is image files `(24*375*3(width, height, channels)images, *.png)` and output is labeled file(.csv) which has Boolean (0 or 1) label.

Here is my github
https://github.com/dldudwo0805/DeepLearningPractice

Plz. Give me advice.

The error code is -

```
The value of a feed cannot be a tf.Tensor object. Acceptable feed values include Python scalars, strings, lists, numpy ndarrays, or TensorHandles.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
y_data = tf.reshape(y_data, [50, 1])
```

y_data is a tensor. Try np.reshape rather than tf.reshape